# PyDev Remote Debugger and Tab Completion in Eclipse

Tags: pydev, remote-debugging, tab-completion

This might be a limitation of the PyDev debugger but would anyone know how to enable tab completion and history like in a plain Python shell in the Eclipse debug Console window?

[image]

Pressing tab or the arrow keys just jumps/moves the cursor. PyDev remote debugger is initialized as needed with following code:

`from pydevsrc import pydevd;pydevd.settrace('<my ip>', stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True, suspend=True)`

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Did you try disabling, restarting, enabling again? To my knowledge this is not an issue on Eclipse in 2017. Please post the solution and accept (your own answer if you like).

Answer (score 0):

Did you check

Preferences -> PyDev -> Editor -> Code Completion -> "Use code completion on debug console sessions?"

Comment: Option is enabled and seems to be enabled by default, bummer.