# pydev remote debuging - code completion in interactive console?

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev, maya

I'm using a Pydev + Eclipse setup to develop a Python script for Autodesk Maya.  In order to debug in Eclipse while the script is running in Maya, the standard setup is to use Pydev's remote debugging feature.
This is all good and everything is working well but with one exception - from within the interactive console during a debugging session, the code completion does not seem to work.  And not just for Maya specific stuff either - for example if I run :

> import sys<ENTER><ENTER>
>   print sys.

and then <CTRL + SPACE> at the console then I still get nothing.
Code completion works fine in the normal code editor, and I have all relevant preferences enabled as far as I know("use code completion in debug sessions" and so on)...

There is a very similar post here, which didn't get resolved:
[PyDev Remote Debugger and Tab Completion in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549574/pydev-remote-debugger-and-tab-completion-in-eclipse/17232238#17232238)

Is this a known issue for remote debugging with Pydev?
(The commercially available WingIDE does have this feature, so it should be possible).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It is not directly an issue with PyDev, because I use completion in the debugger console every day. What do you mean by "remote debugging" exactly? Are you accessing this via some remote desktop or VNC kind of application?

Comment: "remote debugging" means debugging a program within your IDE that was launched from a different application and/or location, see this link:

http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html